# How do I pass a glob or regex locator to the Selenium function alert_is() in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, selenium, webdriver

I'm running a script where I know an alert is going to pop up (mostly) harmlessly that says `$x sequence(s) deleted.` where `$x` is some integer.  I want to get WebDriver to expect the alert and dispense with it, without failing a test case.  For this I'm using `$sel->get_alert()`.  I try passing regex to it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$sel->alert_is("id=regexp:/\d+ sequence\(s\) deleted\./");
```

But the error i get says

```
Unrecognized escape \d passed through at script.pl line 44.
.
.
not ok 14 - get_alert, 'id=regexp:'/d+ sequence(s) deleted./'
Failed test 'get_alert, 'id=regexp:'/d+ sequence(s) deleted./''
at script.pl line 44.
      got: '0 sequence(s) deleted.'
  expected: 'id=regexp:/'d+ sequence(s) deleted./'
```

I get similar results when I try a glob instead of regex.  If I guess the integer and just pass that like this

`$sel->alert_is("0 sequence(s) deleted.");`

It works fine, so I'm pretty sure the Selenese is solid.  When I Google for a solution I just get a lot of different places where people have copied and pasted the CPAN listing for WWW::Selenium, which doesn't give an example for this.

Comment: What does the error tell you? `Unrecognized escape \d`. That is because Perl strings don't know the sequence `\d`, so the backslash is ignored. Strings ne Regexes, which do know that escape. If you want to include a literal backslash in a string, you have to escape it (or use a single-quoted string, where some backslashes are allowed unescaped). Either `'id=regexp:/\d+ sequence\(s\) deleted\./'` or `"id=regexp:/\\d+ sequence\\(s\\) deleted\\./"` has a certain potential to work.

Comment: Changing to single quotes does take care of the 'Unrecognized escape' error but the test is still failing, saying `expected: id=regexp:/\d+ sequence\(s\) deleted\./'`  I don't want to include any literal backslashes, I want to match "0 sequence(s) deleted." where 0 could be any integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if "you know" the alert is going to popup then why not just use `dismiss_alert`? 
From the docs:

Description:
    Dismisses the currently displayed alert dialog. For `comfirm()`
    and `prompt()` dialogs, this is equivalent to clicking the
    'Cancel' button. For `alert()` dialogs, this is equivalent to
    clicking the 'OK' button.

Example:
    `$driver->dismiss_alert;`

Or you can use `accept_alert`.
From the docs:

Description:
    Accepts the currently displayed alert dialog.  Usually, this is
    equivalent to clicking the 'OK' button in the dialog.

Example:
    `$driver->accept_alert;`

Comment: Wow, this question brought back memories!  I opened up this script to find I'd solved the issue like so: `$sel->get_alert() =~ /\d+ sequence.+/;`  However, your way works just as well, so I'll go ahead and call this the accepted answer.